# Excel Data Connection to Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, active-directory

I want to create a data connection in Excel 2007 that pulls the result of an Active Directory query into a sheet in my workbook.

I see that I can do this with VBA: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/01/query-active-directory-from-excel/ but I agree with Rob [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/561218-data-connection-active-directory.html) that it should be easier than that, just using "OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services"

A bit of googling suggests that this is a hole in our collective knowledge that deserves to be filled!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is going to work.  Best work-around I can think of is to use Powershell's export-csv to export your AD query.  Somthing like:

```
get-aduser -filter * | select Name, employeeid, office, postalcode|export-csv "myADexport.csv"
```